# I'm using the sieve of Eratosthenes as a primality test. Why am I getting that 2297 is composite?

Tags: c, algorithm, primes

I am using the Sieve of Eratosthenes to calculate the first 500 prime numbers. What the program does is evauate `n % p` where `n` is the user input and `p` is between 2 and sqrt(n).

I'm testing my program for the case `n = 2297`, which is a prime. Why does my program say it's composite?

```c
bool primalityTestSieve(int n){
    if(n == 2) return true; //tiny complication due to ceil(sqrt(2))

    //Sieve with first MAX
    bool arr[MAX - 1];
    int i, j, s = ceil(sqrt(n));
    for(i = 2; i < MAX; i++){
        arr[i - 2] = true;          //fill arr[] with true
    }
    for(i = 2; i < (int) sqrt(MAX); i++){
        if(arr[i - 2]){
            for(j = i*i; j < MAX; j+= i)
                arr[j - 2] = false;
        }
    }

    //Array storing the primes
    int primes[MAX];
    j = 0;  //Counter for the index of the primes
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        if(arr[i]){
            primes[j] = i + 2;
            j++;
        }

    //Prime test, first using sieve
    for(i = 0; primes[i] <= s; i++)
        if(n % primes[i] == 0) return false;

    //Naive prime test for larger divisors
    for (i = primes[j]; i <= s/2; i++)
            if(((n % 2) == 0)||((n % (2*i + 1)) == 0))  return false;
    return true;
}
```

Note that `MAX` is a parameterised macro and is equal to 500.

Comment: What is the value of `MAX`?  What is the value of `j` after `for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)`?

Comment: @chux I updated the post with reference to `MAX`. The value of `j` is the address of the last element in `primes[]`.

Comment: `//fill arr[] with true` is not so

Comment: @chux Why not? What's wrong with it?

Comment: Let `MAX == 3`.  How may iteraiton with `for(i = 2; i < MAX; i++){` (one).  How many elements in `bool arr[MAX - 1];`  (two).

Comment: oh yeah it should be `<=`. Still doesn't fix the problem though. :(

Comment: Is `s` as expected `sqrt(n)` is prone to slight errors.

Comment: `j = i*i` --> `j = i*2`, remove (or need fix)`for (i = primes[j]; i <= s/2; i++)
            if(((n % 2) == 0)||((n % (2*i + 1)) == 0))  return false;`

Comment: I feel that debugging is the solution here...

Comment: _The value of j is the address of the last element in primes[]_ `j` is last elemnet **next** index.

Comment: Your code is totally borken. Even the `if(n % primes[i] == 0) return false;` will return `false` for the small primes that you just sieved! They're divisible by themselves, as that is the definition of prime! Divisible by only 1 and **itself**! Please debug your algorithm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code uses the sieve to find the primes between `2` and `500`.  (Not the first 500 primes as you seem to say in your text).

Then you copy those primes into the `primes[]` array with `j` as the count of how many items are in the array. So at this point `primes[]` contains some numbers less than `500` followed by a bunch of junk.

Then you have the code:

```
for(i = 0; primes[i] <= s; i++)
```

`s` would be `48` for `n == 2297`. This loop will then check for `n` being divisible by any of the primes up to `48` , which would fail.  (This loop should also have `i < j` as a condition so it does not read into the junk if you enter a large `n`).

However you then write:

```
for (i = primes[j]; i <= s/2; i++)
```

Remmeber that `j` currently holds the prime count, and the primes are in `primes[0]` through `primes[j-1]`. This means `primes[j]` is a junk value; so you set `i` to junk causing undefined behaviour.

(I'm not sure what you were actually trying to do in that last loop, it's unclear where you want to start and finish, or why you test `n%2` every loop iteration, etc. - if you can describe what you are trying to do there then I'll suggest some code).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to fix the problem, as you rightly said it was passing the junk element `primes[j]` to the penultimate for-loop. Regarding the last loop - If the square root of the number inputted is > `MAX`, then the numbers generated by the sieve are not enough to check for primality. I want to test whether `n % p = 0` for all the odd numbers `p` between the last prime generated by the sieve and the square root of the input. Is this carried out correctly?